# Is there a better way to reduce image GET requests than manually combining them?

Tags: webserver, website, apache-http-server

I'm trying to speed up my website. I noticed that each of the the 30+ SVG's that I have (they are tiny logos of open source projects I support) gets its own GET request which just seems absurd. Everywhere I look online says I should combine them into a single image and manually find the location and manually specify the size and offset in a sprite map. This also seems absurd, shouldn't my server be able to blob them together as one file and tell the browser how to cut and rearrange the blob? Why is it up to the programmer to do graphics?

FYI I'm running Apache 2.2 on debian wheezy.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you asking if there is software to automatically convert your images to CSS sprites? Or are you asking why something like [SPDY Server Push](http://www.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-protocol/spdy-protocol-draft3#TOC-3.3-Server-Push-Transactions) is not included in HTTP 1.1?

Comment: I'm looking for something like SPDY Server push (which I didn't know existed until now). It doesn't look like apache supports this yet. Is the framework brand new?

Comment: Google has been working on SPDY for some time. At least _some_ version of SPDY is supported by most browsers now. You may want research mod_spdy, so you can use SPDY with Apache. I've never tried it myself, so I can't help much more. I just hope I was able to point you in the right direction.